# show that $R^n -X$ has at most 2 connected components.

Tags: differential-topology

show that $R^n -X$ has at most 2 connected components.

> **Theprem**: Suppose that $X$ is the boundary of $D$, a compact manifold with boundary and let $F:D \to R^n$ be a smooth map extending $f$; supposed that $z$ is a linear regular value of $F$ that doesn't belong to the image of $f$. Then $F^{-1}(z)$ is a finite set , and $W_2(f,z) =$ #$F^{-1}(z) mod 2$.

I know that  $X$ is a compact, connected hypersurface in $R^n$. $X$ is winding around $R^n$, then $dim(X)=n-1$. Let $z\in R^n$ but not on $X$, then $W_2 (X,z)$ must be $0$ or $1$ depend on whether $z$ lies inside or outside of $X$.

If $z$ lie on the inside of $X$ then $R^n -X$ yield 2 components, otherwise $R^n-X$ still remain as one component.

I'm not sure if I understand this problem correctly, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What conditions are placed on $X$?

Comment: I added more info about $X$, and that's all the book told me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is an $n$-dimensional compact connected submanifold of 
$\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ without boundary, its complement has 2 connected components (this follows from alexander duality).